# Firebase client doesnt recieve message

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following `Node.js script`:

```
    var registrationToken = "Long Token";
var serviceAccount = require("./config/ServiceAccount.json");

var payload = {
    data: {
        score: "850",
        time: "2:45"
    }
};

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: fireBaseConfig.databaseURL
});

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload)
    .then(function(response) {
        // See the MessagingDevicesResponse reference documentation for
        // the contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
```

When running this I do get a `success` response:

```
   Successfully sent message: { results: [ { messageId: '0:1502813815410638%e609af1cf9fd7ecd' } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 0,
  successCount: 1,
  multicastId: 5249778920849394000 }
```

Then i have my client:

```
 firebase.initializeApp(config);

var messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function () {

        messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
            console.log("Message received. ", payload);
            // ...
        });
        console.log('I am in here');

        return messaging.getToken()
            .then(function (currentToken) {
                console.log(currentToken);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
                showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
                setTokenSentToServer(false);
            });



    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error');
    });

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log("Message received. ", payload);
    // ...
});
```

Now first I (as my client) go to the website then I get the token in the console I then use that token in my backend (Node.js) and send a message (while the tap where the client is, is still open) However nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?